# How to manage navigation drawer button?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to do this: when I press to button:

[image]

I want do this: if user (Parse user) has done login, it must show the navigation drawer.
If user isn't logged on, I want to open LoginActivity.java. 
I do this:

```
  ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
    {
        public void onDrawerOpened(View view)
        {

            if(currentUser == null) //utente non loggato
            {
             Intent intent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
              startActivity(intent);
                currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

            }
            else
            {

                super.onDrawerOpened(view);
            }
        }


        public void onDrawerClosed(View v)
        {
            super.onDrawerClosed(v);
        }

    };
```

but it opens also navigation drawer (and I want that opens directly LoginActivity.java).
So I try it:

```
  toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(currentUser == null) //utente non loggato
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

            }

        }
    });
```

but it doesn't work.
So what I have to do?
Thanks

Comment: If you want the navigation `OnClickListener` to fire, you need to disable the toggle's drawer indicator with the `setDrawerIndicatorEnabled()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the Navigation Drawer by `setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);` and **re-enable**(`setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);`) it once the user is successfully logged in.